# how to use requests module inside an appimage?

Tags: python-3.x

background info
made a simple webhooks program in python for an alexa remote then used toga for ui elements. used a combination of docker and briefcase to package into an appimage. as bescribed in beewares tutorial. done on ubuntu 18.04.6 for debian on raspbery pi b3.
im kinda new to making apps so i chose beewares method due to the option to allow app creation for android windows and linux. please note i am more than open to other options if their are better ways

question
how to package python module with my app inside an app image.
when attempting to run the appimage through the terminal window i get a module not found error within the window prompt.
the module in question is the requests module which i believe does not come installed with python

beeware tutorial https://docs.beeware.org/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial-3.html

i tried opening the appimage in other ways and looking into how to import the 'requests' module into the appimage with no avail

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)